# Android Studio: I have 100 list view and i want to open a each new page for each list view when it is pressed

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android and I am making an story app in which I have 100 list view and I want to open a different page for every list view  when it is clicked, but don't want to make 100 new activity. Is There any better way to do this?

Comment: You can use fragment for that. Google it and you will get plenty of results.

Comment: Share your code. Can you please elaborate more so that I can understand better?

Comment: You can use ViewPager with fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have 100 Activities, just have 1 `Activity`(let's say `StoryDetailActivity`) and pass whatever information you want to show on that StoryDetailActivity.
Also, you can pass your `storyId` from your List row click and fetch the complete story details from `StoryDetailActivity`

Refer doc on how to pass data to Activity https://www.dev2qa.com/passing-data-between-activities-android-tutorial/

Also, you can use `Fragment` also and pass data to that.

Let me know if you need further help